# Sci-kit: Can I access a learner's attributes such as .coef_ when using GridSearchCV and Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here's a simplified example with LogisticRegression.  This version (without GridSearchCV and Pipeline) **Works**:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X,y)
print clf.coef_
```

but this **doesn't work** because the GridSearchCV object doesn't have the attribute:

```
lr_pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', LogisticRegression())])
lr_parameters = {}
lr_gs = GridSearchCV(lr_pipeline, lr_parameters)
lr_gs = lr_gs.fit(X,y)
print lr_gs.coef_
```

Is there some way to access it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to operate on the `best_estimator_` obtained from your grid search. You then need to access the `clf` step in your pipeline. Then you can retrieve the coefficients.

```
lr_gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'].coef_
```